# YUI Inline Editing for Dropdown Box

Tags: jquery, yui, inline-editing

I am using inline editing in YUI 2's DataTable.I would like to use dropdown box for this.Does anyone know code for dropdown box?

My Dropdown box would be:

```
<select name ='test' class='selectpicker'><option value='1' >Yes</option><option
```

I tried below code but not getting what to pass

```
{key:"test", label:"test",editor: new YAHOO.widget.DropdownCellEditor({dropdownOptions:YAHOO.example.Data.test,disableBtns:true}), sortable:true},
```

Answer (score -1):

See:  http://www.satyam.com.ar/yui/2.6.0/assortedControls.html

They had not been updated to later versions, but there was no break in compatibility after 2.6 so they should work.  A link at the top of that page points to several other examples which might be of help.